# C# webapi async context issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I got two console applications which calls my webapi the same time and I get back in the console application the follow response from my api:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

So they call at the same time my webapi and then something inside the webapi cannot handle those 2 async calls so this error is returned.

I checked all my code on the webapi project and all methods are async and got  await so I cannot see why I get this.

Here is the code of the webapi.

**Controller:**

```
public class FederationsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IFederationRepository _federationRepository;

    public FederationsController(IFederationRepository federationRepository)
    {
        _federationRepository = federationRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("federations", Name = "GetFederations")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFederations()
    {
        var federations = await _federationRepository.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(federations.ToModel());
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
 public class FederationRepository : IFederationRepository, IDisposable
{
    private Models.DataAccessLayer.CompetitionContext _db = new CompetitionContext();

    #region IQueryable
    private IQueryable<Models.Entities.Federation> FederationWithEntities()
    {
        return _db.Federations.Include(x => x.Clubs)
                              .Where(x => !x.DeletedAt.HasValue && x.Clubs.Any(y => !y.DeletedAt.HasValue));
    }
    #endregion IQueryable

public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.Entities.Federation>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await FederationWithEntities().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

**Mapper**

```
public static class FederationMapper
{
    public static List<Federation> ToModel(this IEnumerable<Models.Entities.Federation> federations)
    {
        if (federations == null) return new List<Federation>();
        return federations.Select(federation => federation.ToModel()).ToList();
    }

    public static Federation ToModel(this Models.Entities.Federation federation)
    {
        return new Federation()
        {
            Name = federation.Name,
            FederationCode = federation.FederationCode,
            CreatedAt = federation.CreatedAt,
            UpdatedAt = federation.UpdatedAt
        };
    }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class CompetitionContext : DbContext
{
    public CompetitionContext() : base("ContextName")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Federation> Federations { get; set; }
}
```

**UnityConfig**

```
 public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IFederationRepository, FederationRepository>();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
}
}
```

Thank you for all the advices/help.

Comment: I would check to see if something is causing your unity registration to be messed up, it is acting like a single IFederationRepository is being shared between requests. Try explicitly setting a `TransientLifetimeManger` in the unity registration to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I tried this container.RegisterType<IFederationRepository, FederationRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager()); but that did also not solve the problem if that is what you mean?

Comment: `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` is the absolute wrong manager to use, you need a new copy of the class per resolve. You need a `TransientLifetimeManger`

Comment: There is something missing, that exception is only thrown when you are executing two async methods concurrently without using await on both. Please add the stack trace for your exception, I suspect your repository is not the problem (even though you should rewrite it like Simon said in his answer).

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Thanks you solved the problem I checked my exception trace again and saw that before each request to the api he also do some security which got also a dbcontext. I changed all methods with the using(var db = new CompetitionContext()) and now it runs very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your repository you are creating a single CompetitionContext and reusing it. I'm assuming that IoC setup is registring the repository as some kind of single instance, so the same repository is getting used every time. If that's the case you should create a new CompetitionContext for each method call.

Also, probably should make sure it's closed with a using statement.

I'm also not clear from your code snippets why you are returning an IQueryable from that FederationWithEntities, method, do you have other things that are using it?

Anyway, I'd probably change that GetAllMethod to be something like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.Entities.Federation>> GetAllAsync()
{
  using (Models.DataAccessLayer.CompetitionContext _db = new CompetitionContext())
  {
     return _db.Federations.Include(x => x.Clubs)
                           .Where(x => !x.DeletedAt.HasValue && x.Clubs.Any(y => !y.DeletedAt.HasValue))
                           .ToListAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: Or make sure the context is per request.

Comment: `RegisterType` should by default create a new `FederationRepository` every call of the constructor for the controller, and the constructor is called once per request. Each new `FederationRepository` creates a new `CompetitionContext`.

Comment: I tried this solution but it does not solve the problem.